# How to select child nodes at unknown child element location using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

My XML file consists of a structure that resembles something like the following:

```
<root>
    <Manager name="1">
        <Manager name="2">
            <Employee name="3">
        </Manager>
        <Manager name="abe">
        </Manager>
        <Employee name="4">
        <Employee name="5">
    </Manager>
</root>
```

The XML feeds a treeview, and depending on where in the treeview a user clicks, I either want to retrieve the Employee clicked on (which is easy, as I can use `treeview.SelectedNode`), or otherwise in case the click was on the root node, or a manager node, the first employee under the manager.

I.e.

- Clicking on `root` should show details of `Employee 4` (the first Employee record  is directly under `Manager 1` directly under `root`).
- Clicking on `Manager 1` also should show `Employee 4`.
- Clicking `Manager 2` should show `Employee 3`.
- Clicking `Manager Abe` yields no results.
- `Employee 5` only shows when there is a click directly on that employee.

It could also be possible that `Manager 1` does not have any direct employees under him. In that case, clicking on root should yield the first Employee under the first manager with employees. So if we assume `Employee 4` and `Employee 5` were not under `Manager 1`, clicking on root would yield `Employee 3`.

I tried using some different variants of `Element`, `Elements`, `Descendant` and `Descendants`, and am a bit stuck.

I suppose that I could write scenarios for every individual combination (I.e. `rootClicked`, `managerClicked` and `employeeClicked`), which is what I did originally, but I'm looking for something that will hopefully be easier to maintain, code-wise.

I had good hopes that using root.Element("Employee") would help, but that threw a `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Xml.Linq.XEelement'.  'select' not found` error.

Would anyone be able to supply me with that little nudge I need to solve my issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using XPath**:

```
ClickedNode.XPathEvaluate
    ("self::Employee | self::Manager/Employee[1] | self::root/Manager[1]/Employee[1]")
```

---

**Update**:

Answer to the edited question:

**Use**:

```
 ClickedNode[self::Employee]
|
 ClickedNode[not(self::Employee)]/descendant-or-self::Manager[Employee][1]/Employee[1]
```

**This selects either**:

a. The clicked node, if it is an `Employee'

Or:

b. The first child `Employee` of the first desendant-or-self of the clicked node, that is a manager and has a child `Employee`

**And, if ClickedNode is an `XElement` (or `XNode`), then do**:

```
  ClickedNode.XPathEvaluate
        (self::*[self::Employee]
      | self::node()[not(self::Employee)]
                       /descendant-or-self::Manager[Employee][1]/Employee[1]
        )
```

---

**Finally, here is a complete C# code**:

**A static class named `TestLinqXpath`**:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace TestLinqXpath
{
    public  static class TestLinqXpath
    {
        public static XElement SelectNearestDescendantEmployee(XElement clicked)
        {
            string Expr =
@"(self::*[self::Employee]
 | self::node()[not(self::Employee)]
           /descendant-or-self::Manager[Employee][1]/Employee[1]
   )";
            XElement result = clicked.XPathSelectElement(Expr);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**and extensive test**:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace TestLINQ_Xml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            string xml = 
@"<root>
    <Manager name='1'>
        <Manager name='2'>
            <Employee name='3'/>
        </Manager>
        <Manager name='abe'>
        </Manager>
        <Employee name='4'/>
        <Employee name='5'/>
    </Manager>
</root>";
            XElement top = XElement.Parse(xml);

            XElement cliked1 = top;
            XElement res1 = TestLinqXpath.TestLinqXpath.SelectNearestDescendantEmployee(cliked1);
            Console.WriteLine(res1.ToString());

            XElement cliked2 = top.XPathSelectElement("Manager[@name='1']");
            XElement res2 = TestLinqXpath.TestLinqXpath.SelectNearestDescendantEmployee(cliked2);
            Console.WriteLine(res2.ToString());

            XElement cliked3 = top.XPathSelectElement(".//Manager[@name='2']");
            XElement res3 = TestLinqXpath.TestLinqXpath.SelectNearestDescendantEmployee(cliked3);
            Console.WriteLine(res3.ToString());

            XElement cliked4 = top.XPathSelectElement(".//Manager[@name='abe']");
            XElement res4 = TestLinqXpath.TestLinqXpath.SelectNearestDescendantEmployee(cliked4);
            Console.WriteLine((res4 != null) ? res4.ToString() : "null");

            XElement cliked5 = top.XPathSelectElement(".//Employee[@name='5']");
            XElement res5 = TestLinqXpath.TestLinqXpath.SelectNearestDescendantEmployee(cliked5);
            Console.WriteLine(res5.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**When this test is run, the wanted, correct results are produced:**

```
<Employee name="4" />
<Employee name="4" />
<Employee name="3" />
null
<Employee name="5" />
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the results returned as an XElement, but then get the following error when trying your solution: `Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.`.

The syntax looks promising though.

Comment: @SchmitzIT, There was a typo in the expression -- try it now.

Comment: Thanks :) However, it still throws an error when I try retrieving it as an XElement:

<pre>Unable to cast object of type '<EvaluateIterator>d__0`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.</pre>

Comment: @SchmitzIT, As the error message explains, the result of XPathEvaluate is of type `object`. It has to be *cast* to the expected result object type. I would recommend that you read the respective MSDN documentation, including specific code examples.

Comment: Would you be able to nudge me a bit further? I really found the documentation lacking. I use a workaround now where I only show details in case an actual employee is clicked, and just show nothing when a manager node was clicked, but in the long run I'd not mind solving this the proper way.

Comment: @SchmitzIT, I have updated this answer to cover your new, clarified requirements -- please, have a look.

Comment: @SchmitzIT, I updated the answer again. Now there is complete C# code.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to give this a shot. I'll award you the bounty, for the extensive answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This **linq2xml** shoud do

```
doc.Descendants("Manager").Where(n=>n.Attribute("name").Value=="yourManagerID")
.Select(
x=>x.Elements("Employee").Count()!=0 
?
x.Elements("Employee").First().Attribute("name").Value
:
x.Elements("Manager").First().Element("Employee").Atrribute("name").Value
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, seeing we're responding to a click in a treeview that could happen at any given location, we do not know the ManagerID in advance.

Comment: @SchmitzIT u can replace `yourManagerID` with the selected managerid

Comment: I must be dumb or something, as I cannot seem to figure this out. I'm trying to stuff the results of the query into an XElement, and tried casting it as such, but end up getting an error message: `Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.`

I'm pondering forgetting the whole concept of automatically finding the first employee, and only return results in case the node clicked was an employee